# Have ENO/WENO now completely supplanted older methods?

Tags: conservation, weno, flux-limiters

Is it true that ENO/WENO schemes are the "goat" and they completely supplanted the older methods such as Godunov, approximate Riemann solvers, flux limiters etc? Are these old methods only important in classrooms to motivate and pave the way for the ultimate "boss" ENO/WENO?

Comment: In my experience, approximate Riemann solvers and flux limiters are very common in large scale CFD work.